# VBA Excel Download webpage complete

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to download a complete webpage. In other words automate this process:

1- Open the webpage
2- Click on Save as
3- Select Complete
4- Close the webpage.

This is what I've got so far:

```
URL = "google.com" 'for TEST
Dim IE
Set IE = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False
IE.Navigate URL
Do
Loop While IE.Busy = True
Dim i
Dim Filename
i = 0
Filename = "C:\Test.htm"
IE.Document.ExecCommand "SaveAs", False, Filename
```

When I run the code in the last line a save file dialog appears. Is there any way to suppress this?

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Save As dialog [*cannot* be suppressed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537418(VS.85).aspx):

> The Save HTML Document dialog cannot be suppressed when calling this method from script.

It is also a modal dialog and you cannot automate the way to click the "Save" button. VBA execution pauses while waiting manual user input when faced with a dialog of this sort.

Rather than using the `IE.Document.ExecCommand` method, you could try to read the page's HTML and print that to a file using standard I/O functions.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SaveHTML()
Dim URL as String
Dim IE as Object
Dim i as Long
Dim FileName as String
Dim FF as Integer

URL = "http://google.com" 'for TEST
Filename = "C:\Test.htm"

Set IE = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate URL
Do
Loop While IE.Busy

'Creates a file as specified
' this will overwrite an existing file if already exists
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile FileName

FF = FreeFile
Open Filename For Output As #FF

With IE.Document.Body
    Print #FF, .OuterHtml & .InnerHtml
End With

Close #FF

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

I am not sure whether this will give you exactly what you want, or not.  There are other ways to get data from web and probably the best would be to get the raw HTML from an [XMLHTTP request](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Silent-SaveAs-webpageHelp-needed-m64627.aspx) and print that to a file.

Of course, it is rarely the case that we actually need an entire web page in HTML format, so if you are looking to then scrape particular data from a web page, the XMLHTTP and DOM would be the best way to do this, and it's not necessary to save this to a file at all.

Or, you could use the Selenium wrapper to automate IE, which is much more robust than using the relatively few native methods to the InternetExplorer.Application class.

Note also that you are using a rather crude method of waiting for the web page to load (`Loop While IE.Busy`). While this *may* work sometimes, it may not be reliable. There are dozens of questions about how to do this properly here on SO, so I would refer you to the search feature here to tweak that code a little bit.